# Listener in Ruby: Bunny Gem or AMQP gem

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to make a listener in `Ruby` which will read messages from a channel on every half-an-hour. I am confused on which Gem to use: `Bunny` (https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) or `AMQP` (http://rubyamqp.info)? I am aware that Bunny is easy-to-use. But will that solve my purpose?

Answer (score 4):

How will your script be triggered? What's the volumes in question? Will the processing be done sequentially or in some sort of event-based system? Both libraries are essentially the same - except for one core difference.

Bunny is used for sequential processing. A message is popped off the queue, processed then acknowledged, before the next message is retrieved. To scale this, you should use either threads or processes to process more messages at once.

The AMQP gem is Event-based and runs inside an EventMachine reactor. This is ideally suited to light workloads where RabbitMQ or another external service would be the bottleneck. Using AMQP gem, a consumer will consume as many messages as possible (or told to), and fire off individual callbacks for each message. If the callbacks make their own network calls, this is probably the best solution as it allows Ruby to interleave the network communication most effectively.

Short summary, but basically for a rarely-running script I'd suggest the sequential nature of Bunny, especially if you've not worked in EventMachine before. It's hard to answer fully without knowledge of your workload.

Take a look at [jondot/sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) for a ready-made Bunny framework.

Comment: Thanks boffbowsh, your comparison helped me to make my decision that I probably want to try Bunny first to solve my problem domain which is retrieve all messages (estimate about 0-20 messages) every 5 seconds

Comment: Bunny worked great for my needs. This resource was very helpful http://rubybunny.info/articles/getting_started.html and this one http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html - for my learning application I ended up using the pull API to get messages off the queue 1 at a time